# Can't assign weights as expected

Tags: weight-painting

[Blender File Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QOacbDmriys1ojKw6KbnFj_9Bl_6XBDw) I have been rigging a mushroom character having hands.The model has a mirror modifier. When I'm assigning weights automatically, in non-mirrored hands,i.e left hand, weights assigned well but also assinged weights of right hand in left hand bone. Whenever I move Left hand bone it moves both the left and rights hands. I flipped names,recreated armature from the beggining but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is apply the mirror modifier.  Then you can re-parent the bones to the mesh with automatic weights with no problem.
Hope this is the answer you needed.

Comment: Gee Thanks. It worked.

Comment: no, thank you.  I could use the reputation points :)

Comment: But I'm modelling this by seeing a tutorial. In that tutorial he didnt applied it. Also making so many things without applying it. How?

Comment: What do you mean by "making so many things without applying it"?  Is there a reason you don't want to apply it?

Comment: perhaps you could link the tutorial?